# Background color/width running to 100% on css element

Tags: css

I'm trying to get the white background behind the title to remain at the width of the text, not run all the way to the right of the screen, as it's doing now:

http://www.jmakhotels.com/post-ranch-inn-california-big-sur-new/

It should look like this: http://www.jmakhotels.com/images/title-tag.jpg ... but I can't figure out how to set the width so that it's dynamic for the different title lengths. This should be simple, but it's driving me insane! That .header-title element should simply be the width of the text + 10x padding on the left and right.

Here's the CSS for the blue div (which will be an image bgd), and the title element:

```
.main-header {
background-color: #009cff;
width: 100%;
height: 300px;

}

.header-title {
    margin: -58px 0 0 18px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    width:auto;

}
```

Thanks so much to anyone who can help me figure this out.

Comment: Are you able to move the h2 into the `#content` div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `display:table` on the `.header-title` rule will fix the issue (*without messing the margins*).

Comment: This worked--just curious why? Thank you in either case!

Comment: @hudsonian It makes the element act as a `<table>` element which wraps around the content.

Answer (score 2):

Your .header-title (h2) is a block element, it should be a inline-block element to grab the width of the element itself.

However, your header-title can be placed inside the main-header instead of below the element.
A quick fix would be to move the .header-title element from below the .main-header div to the inside:

```
<div class="main-header">
    <h2 class="header-title">This will be the title</div>
</div>
```

You want the header title to stick to the bottom of the main header, you can do this by giving it an absolute position. First we need to give the main header a relative position:

```
.main-header {
    position: relative;
}
```

Now we can position header-title to the bottom of the main-header element:

```
h2.header-title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; <- stick to the bottom of main-header
    left: 1em;
}
```

You can remove the margin from the header-title class in your CSS, because you're already telling header-title to stick to the bottom of main-header.

Comment: Thanks so much for this very thorough answer--totally helpful. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Change `.header-title` to `display:inline-block` then add `margin-bottom: -36px;` to `.main-header`

So:

```
.main-header {
    background-color: #009cff;
    height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: -36px;
    width: 100%;
}

.header-title {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    display: inline-block;
    margin: -58px 0 0 18px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Also don't need `width:auto`

Comment: @hudsonian You are welcome.  Glad you got an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the style display: inline-block;

I am assuming .header-title is being used on a div that surrounds the title. You also shouldn't need width: auto;